# What does the Chinese symbols mean?

Tags: translation

[image: [!90s tattoo on the right ankle]

I'm trying to find a translation of the ankle tattoo on the photo below.

Answer (score 2):

**CC-CEDICT**

> 姊〔姉〕
>
> PY zǐ
>
> ZY ㄗˇ
>
> OLD VARIANT OF 姊 zǐ (or jiě) {zi2}
>
> 1 older sister
>
> 2 Taiwan pr. [jiě]

**KEY**

> (variant of zǐ 姊) elder sister